# Hadoop 2.9.2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm managed to setup Hadoop with 3 datanodes as a small cluster and everything work ok.
 When trying to access AWS bucket on S3A protocol I get this error:

> hadoop fs -ls s3a://my-bucket/

```
-ls: Fatal internal error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:380)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2393)
    ... 16 more
```

What I did wrong ? How do fix that ?

P.S. Bucket on Amazon if fully public. Anyone can download from it.

Amazon credentials was configured in `hadoop/core-site.xml` as described here: [Hadoop-AWS module: Integration with Amazon Web Services](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)

Comment: As per the link you shared  the issue seems to be related JAR file missing from CLASSPATH. Can you check if it is accessible. If it is not can you copy required JARS as shown below matching your hadoop version and retry.Also try replacing s3a with s3 and see if it's helping.                                                                                
 sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/

sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/

Comment: s3:/my-bucket -> No FileSystem for scheme "s3",  s3n://my-bucket  -> No FileSystem for "s3n". After copying the jars - no changes :( same exception

Comment: How I can add folder /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/   to CLASSPATH of hadoop ?

Comment: I would recommend using EMR instead. Must easier to get a cluster running

Comment: @bdcloud - could you post an answer ? After I copy the JAR files to **correct** location it star to work. You are right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the link you shared the issue seems to be related JAR file missing from CLASSPATH. Can you check if it is accessible. If it is not can you copy required JARS as shown below matching your Hadoop version and retry.

```
sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/$AWS_JAVA_SDK_VERSION.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/

sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/$AWS_HADOOP_VERSION.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/
```

Comment: If its hadoop 2.9.2 then you *must* have the hadoop-aws-2.9.2 JAR and matching aws SDK - aws-java-sdk-bundlle-1.11.199.jar` if you download the hadoop tar you'll get this. No matter what anyone else says *do not try and mix hadoop or AWS SDK jars*. You'll only see different stack traces

Comment: @SteveLoughran  Can you let me know why the answer is down voted.I have clearly stated that "matching your Hadoop version" and confirmed it is working.Now can you tell me the exact reason why it is down voted?

Comment: author said "2.9.2", you said "copy the 2.7.5 artifacts in". That's not going to help, really.

Comment: how about you remove the numbers and jsut put in some $HADOOP_VERSION and $AWS_SDK_VERSION vars, so people won't try and copy & paste in the values. That's all I really care about

Comment: @SteveLoughran Thank you for the suggestion.I have updated my answer.